# Optimizing prallel computing for nested integration

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, syntax, parallelization, nested-function

I need an advice for optimization of computing with `ParallelMap`, as well as general hints to speed up computing discussed below. I have several questions about this topic and decided to ask them all together here.

I try to calculate the following expression as a numerical list:
$$F_{tot}(X,A)=\int\limits_0^A\mathrm{d}g\int\limits_0^1\mathrm{d}j\int\limits_0^1\mathrm{d}a\int\limits_0^1\mathrm{d}b\ \ f_2(g,j,A)\ \ \left[\int\limits_0^A\mathrm{d}c\int\limits_0^1\mathrm{d}e\ \ f_1(a,b,c,e,X)\right]^2$$
for different values of $A$ and $X$ given in 2D list, e.g,

```
L=Table[{A,X}, {A,1,8,4},{X,1,121,5}]
```

All the computations I intend to perform are done on a machine with 16 physical cores and 16 virtual ones, as a result I want to use the parallel computation.

In Mathematica's code, after several tries, I stopped at the following implementation:

```
L = Table[{X, A}, {X, 1, 121, 5}, {A, 1, 8, 4}];

(*f1 and f2 are given such a trivial for simplicity, but, in fact, it is
a skyscraper of Bessel functions. It is indeed massy, about 1000 lines
when transformed to Matlab code*)
f1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ, X_?NumericQ] := a + b + c + e^X;
f2[g_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := g + j^A;

F1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, X_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[f1[a, b, c, e, X], {c, 0, A}, {e, 0, 1},
   WorkingPrecision -> 5];
Ftot[{X_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ}] := NIntegrate[f2[g, j, A] (F1[a, b, X, A])^2,
{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {g, 0, A}, {j, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 7] ;

ParallelMap[Ftot, L, {-2}]
```

Now to the bothering issues:

**1.** Accidentally, I have found, when implementing `ParallelMap[Ftot, L, {-2}]`, for the list initiated as

```
L1 = Table[{X, A}, {X, 1, 121, 5}, {A, 1, 8,4}];
ParallelMap[Ftot, L1, {-2}]
```

computing is loading all cores for about 60% during the first half of the processing time, and then dropping down to about 34%. Contrary, when I initiate `L` list differently, namely as

```
L2 = Table[{X, A}, {A, 1, 8, 4}, {X, 1, 121, 5}];
ParallelMap[Ftot, L2, {-2}]
```

i.e. transpose version of the first case, only a few cores are busy and the overall load of the processor is only 9%.

Do I understand correctly that computing speed is intolerant to the input list shape? How can I find the optimal size of the input list `L` to homogeneously load all 16 cores? I suspect that 16 cores processed the first 16 elements of the `L1` list and they were busy for 60%, and then residual 9 elements occupied 16 cores as 60%$\frac{9}{16} \approx$ 34%. Are these thoughts correct and the length of the list has to be a multiple of a number of cores, i.e. 16?

**2.** Instead of `ParallelMap`, at the beginning, I tried to use `ParallelTable`, such as:

```
ParallelTable[Ftot[X, A], {X, 1, 121, 5}, {A, 1, 8,4}];
```

but, subjectively, it took longer than with any of the `L1` or `L2` `ParallelMap` procedures (I did not use clocks to count that time). Might it be the case? What might be the reason for such a drastic difference?

**3.** I will appreciate any comments on improving the code in general. I am new here and my background is mostly Matlab and Python, therefore, some features look puzzling to me right now. Any advice to increase the CPU loading extent above 60%? Any good manuals on the nested integration and parallelized computations in Mathematica?

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Any thoughts concerning listed issues ?

Comment: Integration doesn't necessarily strike me as a good target for parallel evaluation. Why do you think it would help?

Comment: Simple answer is tests showed so. If you have multicore CPU you can try your own. The difference between normal Mapping and parallel is circa 4 times, I guess depending on a PC's performance, but for my one it was so.

With whole respect, I will appreciate if we talk about issues outlined not your doubts or, please, reformulate them to less abstract way.

Comment: According to the documentation of `ParallelMap`, "parallelization happens at the outermost level used".  The outermost level for `L2` has only two elements, so I would expect only two kernels to be used.  After some experimentation, I found that `L1f = Flatten[L1, 1]; ParallelMap[Ftot, L1f]` was fastest, although not by much.  Incidentally, I found that `ParallelTable[Ftot[{X, A}], {X, 1, 121, 5}, {A, 1, 8, 4}]` was slightly faster than `ParallelMap[Ftot, L1, {-2}]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you for your comment. I suspect that the speed of `ParallelMap` and `ParallelTable` is sensible to the equation itself. In fact this parallelization topic is way complicated and has many pitfalls I did not suspect of before. Thank you. I will try to `Flatten` the input list  for the next time, and believe it will load the processor efficiently.